# retrieve tasks that are scheduled in coming week

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, dayofweek

I'm trying to retrieve all the tasks that are scheduled for the coming week.

I might be doing it totally wrong but this is what I am trying so far,

```
  var dateArray = stringDate.split('/');
  const taskDate = dateArray[0];      
  if(taskDate <= new Date().getDate()+7) 
  {
      //retrieve the tasks
  }
```

the stringDate contains the date in this format 1/5/2022

Comment: I suggest using moment.js for date comparison if your application exclusively deals with this kind of operations heavily.

Comment: If you show what `stringDate` looks like, then you'll get a much better answer. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the part about including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: From my understanding of the question, you first need to get the day of current date. Then keep incrementing the date until the day == Sunday && date != current date, once this is true, retrieve the task of that particular date and for subsequently for next 6 dates.